# Xml Python loop getiterator() doesn't iterate all tree

Tags: python, xml, liclipse

I have xml file like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
```

and another similar file 
And i have this code

```
   w1 = tree1.getiterator()
    w2=tree2.getiterator()
    for elt in w1:
        for el2 in w2:
            print(elt.tag,el2.tag)
```

I obtain this result

```
data data
data country
data rank
data year
data gdppc
data neighbor
data neighbor
```

I do not know why it does not iterate the first loop

Answer (score 0):

The *iterator* is *exhausted* after the first iteration over `w2` so you only see the first tag from `w1` and all the tags from `w2` once. You would need to create a list of tags so you can repeatedly iterate over the tags of w2:

```
w2 = list(tree2.getiterator()) # store tags in a list
for elt in w1:
    for el2 in w2:
        print(elt.tag, el2.tag)
```

Or reset `w2` each time.

```
for elt in w1:
    for el2 in w2:
        print(elt.tag, el2.tag)
    w2 = tree2.getiterator() # recreate iterator
```